# Delete data in response array with php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have a array as in the example. With the code I wrote, I get an output like in **Output1**.

Question: I am requesting a service different from my own application. The answer is an array and it contains id information. There is permission () for authorization control. The permission function returns user privileges as true and false. But I couldn't write the correct syntax because I couldn't remember this function completely. When I use my own code, I can pull the users who have permission as in output1. But I want the pagination information to remain in the array. As in Output2. What method should I apply?

This array is an example. I just tried to explain my own problem.

My code=>(Laravel 5.8)

```
$response = ….get(url)………

$list = $response->getBody()[‘content’];

$collection = collect($list);

$filtered = $collection->filter(function ($item) [
    return auth()->user->permission($item['id'])
]);

Return [‘content’ => $filtered];
```

Raw Response:

```
[
  "paginate"=> 
  [
      "page"=> 5,
      "per_page"=> 20,
      "page_count"=> 20,
      "total_count"=> 521,
      "Links"=> [
        ["self"=> "/products?page=5&per_page=20"],
        ["first"=> "/products?page=0&per_page=20"],
      ]
  ],
  "content"=> [
    [
      "id"=> 1,
      "name"=> "Widget #1",
    ],
    [
      "id"=> 2,
      "name"=> "Widget #2",
    ],
    [
      "id"=> 3,
      "name"=> "Widget #3",
    ]
  ]
]
```

Output1:

```
[
  "content"=> 
  [
      "id"=> 1,
      "name"=> "Widget #1",
    ],
   ----------------------> Authorized users(id= 1, 3) here, but no pagination.
[
      "id"=> 3,
      "name"=> "Widget #3",
    ]
  ]
```

expected output:

```
[
  "paginate"=> 
  [
      "page"=> 5,
      "per_page"=> 20,
      "page_count"=> 20,
      "total_count"=> 521,
      "Links"=> [
        ["self"=> "/products?page=5&per_page=20"],
        ["first"=> "/products?page=0&per_page=20"],
      ]
  ],
  "content"=> [
    [
      "id"=> 1,
      "name"=> "Widget #1",
      "uri"=> "/products/1"
    ],
    [
      "id"=> 3,
      "name"=> "Widget #3",
      "uri"=> "/products/3"
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but the "example" and "Output2" look the same to me (minus the record with id 2 in the latter)

Comment: @patrickQ yes you are right, i just want to delete id 2 without breaking the basic json structure. I'm losing all paginate information in Output1. After deleting id 2, I want a json to remain in output2

Comment: Please include the actual code that you used in the body of the question.

Comment: Also, your example JSON isn't actually valid JSON.  Please provide us with something that is useable and a true representation of the JSON used by your code.

Comment: @PatrickQ  I can't share real Json data, Because I don't have access right now. I added the code I used with Laravel. User permissions return me with the permission () function as true and false. I want to delete the unauthorized ones.

Comment: Is `example` supposed to be `$collection` before it is filtered and `output1` is what you are getting after it is filtered?

Comment: Please specify what `$item['WILL DELETE']` _really is_, and also include the `permission()` function.  Is there any code between `$list = $response->getBody();` and `$collection = collect($list);`?  Because I imagine that `$list` is probably just a string representation of the JSON at that point, and I don't believe that `collect()` will do anything (nothing you want, anyway) with that.

Comment: Also, you may want to change the title of this question, as it seems you are really asking about how to filter Laravel collections.  That isn't the same is editing a JSON string.

Comment: @patrickQ I tried to explain the question again. It became more revealing

Comment: `$list = $response->getBody()[‘content’];`  I'd wager a lot of money that that's not what you actually have.  Not if you are actually getting the result that you claim to be.  Please copy/paste your _exact_ code. Do _not_ try to rewrite it by hand.  Please know that trying to be vague and imprecise wastes both your time and ours.

Comment: Yes, I tried to write as far as I can remember there are errors in the code and the article. $ list = $ response-> getBody () [‘content’]; this line really works. I will share it for you :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but you've changed the code and "example" content so many times, I'm afraid I can no longer help you.

Comment: @patrickq Yes you are right, this is my fault.  I have no chance to reach the code. As I remembered, I had to change the content.  Thank you for your support

Comment: Can you give a valid array @BarisOZER I cant try your array, `print_r($YourArray);` and add that array under the question as an update.

Answer (score 2):

So, if what are you saying is correct it looks like you are already properly filtering your `content` to exclude those with the unwanted `id`s. Good job! Now, you want the JSON back that also contains your pagination data. First let's step through your code to see how we ended up here:

```
$response = ….get(url)………

$list = $response->getBody()[‘content’];
```

Right here, in the first two lines, we see that you have selected ONLY the `content` from your response body and stored it in `$list`.

```
$collection = collect($list);

$filtered = $collection->filter(function ($item) [
    return auth()->user->permission($item['id'])
]);
```

Now, you're taking that `content` and filtering it based on `id`.

```
Return [‘content’ => $filtered];
```

And, lastly, you are returning the filtered `content`. So, nothing has been deleted at all - you've just pulled out the `content`, filtered it, and returned it. Your `pagination` data is still sitting right where you left it. In order to get the JSON you want to return you could adjust the way you are pulling out `content` and filtering it, but since I don't know many details of what you're doing or why and your filter is already working my instinct is *why bother*? You could just take your `pagination` data and combine it with your filtered `content` and then you would have exactly what you're looking for:

```
$response = ….get(url)………

$list = $response->getBody()[‘content’];
$pagination = $response->getBody()[‘pagination’];

$collection = collect($list);

$filtered = $collection->filter(function ($item) [
    return auth()->user->permission($item['id'])
]);

$alldata = // combine your pagination and filtered objects 

Return [‘data’ => $alldata];
```

Note that I did not show how to combine `pagination` and the filtered `content` - this is because I'm not sure what type of objects you've got at this point. Since your sample output is not really proper JSON I'm not sure if `pagination` really is supposed to be a list/array or if it's just the way you've written your examples, I'm not sure if these are strings or if they've been parsed, etc. So strings would require appending one to the other, collections would use `combine()`, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

**Your array is an invalid array** ! So I couldnt try it, as I mentioned in comment!

What I understand from reading all your edits, Here some examples how you can remove id 2 from array in php:

**Before starting** : we have an option to ignore id 2 in php where clause like so

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id NOT IN (2)

OR 

SELECT FROM table WHERE id <> 2
```

You can ignore id 2 when querying then you will have an array without id 2, lets contine with arrays

if you want to remove a specific value in array do the following.

**Remove from an Associative Array**

```
   $YourArray = array("id"=>"2","name"=>"somename");

    //use array key exist to find if id exist

    $test = array_key_exists("id",$YourArray);
      if($test == 2){
        unset($YourArray['id']); //Here you unset id 2
      }
    print_r($YourArray); //result of new array
```

**Second solution with multdimential arrays**:

```
// PHP program to creating two  
// dimensional associative array 
$data = array( 

    // Ankit will act as key 
    "paginate" => array( 

        // Subject and marks are 
        // the key value pair 
        "id" => 1, 
        "name" => "Widget #1",  
        "uri"=> "/products/1"
    ), 

    // Ram will act as key 
    "content" => array( 

        // Subject and marks are 
        // the key value pair 
        "id" => 2, 
        "name" => "Widget #1",  
        "uri"=> "/products/1"
    ),  
); 

echo "Display Marks: \n"; 


foreach ($data as $key => $subArr) {
    if($subArr['id'] == 2){
    unset($subArr['id']);
    $data[$key] = $subArr; 
    }
}
print_r($data);
```

Here is the demo : https://3v4l.org/mvZPN

**If you want to remove id and all its elements in array** : `array_filter();` used

```
$test = array_filter($data, function($data) { return $data['id'] != 2; });

print_r($test);
```

Here is the demo : https://3v4l.org/UgNqu